# How can I keep a stack variable from overwriting a static array in C++ with GCC?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I have a problem in which an array that is declared on the stack as an automatic variable overwrites an array that is declared statically.  I cannot quote the exact code both for reasons of size and of intellectual property, but the outline follows.

I have the following struct:

```
struct mystruct_type {
    const int list_size;
    const int* list;
};
```

I have a global static array of these structs:

```
struct mystruct_type mystruct_ar[] = {
    {3, (int[]){1, 2, 3}},
    {2, (int[]){1, 3}},
    {5, (int[]){4, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
};
```

This array is in a source file that's compiled into a library.

I have another source file that's compiled into another library that has an automatic array:

```
void my_func(void) 
{
    char my_string[1000];

    // etc...
}
```

When this is all linked together, I see that the address of *one* of the `list`s in `mystruct_ar`, overlaps with `my_string`, and when I copy something into `my_string` it overrides elements in that `list`, causing a variety of problems.

My understanding of how the compiler and the linker work is that the static array and all of its subarrays belong in one region of memory, while the stack (on which `my_string` is declared) is in a separate non-overlapping region.  What could be causing this overlap?  What can I check?

I'm using GCC 4.3.2 on SuSE10 Linux (x86-64_linux26).  Everything is linked statically.

**EDIT:** a few comments below said that this doesn't compile.  They are right.  In the process of sanitizing my snippet for presentation I neglected to cast the `list` array to `int[]`.  This is fixed above.

Comment: Does valgrind complains when running the code ?

Comment: This does not compile. An attempt is being made to initialise an `int*` to many `int`s. For a test I would suggest changing `const int*` to `const int[10]` to determine if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this code would compile. Specifically, you can't pass a { list, of, ints } in mystruct_ar for the list pointer. You would have to declare each array of ints separately above.

You need to present a coherent sample that actually demonstrates the error, or failing that, actual code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the stack is determined at runtime, not at compile-time. Run `ulimit -s` to find out the current maximum stack size, and pass an argument (like `ulimit -s 16384`) to increase it. Both of my Linux machines showed 8192 as the current stack size, try increasing it and see if your app works better.

Comment: Blowing the stack limit results in a crash, not a memory stomp.

Comment: @StilesCrisis "Blowing the stack limit results in a crash". That's true only under *some* specific conditions, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing this overlap?

You didn't say whether you are using multiple threads. If you are, it is very likely that `my_string` overflows the (limited) stack, and thus un-intentionally overlaps global data.

The typical stack on Linux is 8MB, with a default guard region of 1 page (== 4K). This makes it unlikely that you are actually overflowing the stack (8MB is quite large) and that a 1000-element `my_string` can "step over" the guard region without touching it (touching the guard region results in `SIGSEGV`).

However, it is likely that you have not told us all the relevant details. If you create threads with non-default attributes, perhaps you are creating them with a small stack and disabling guard region?

Worse yet, you might be creating a thread with a fixed stack region (via `pthread_attr_setstackaddr`), and that fixed stack region might be a global array. If you (or some third-party code you call) do *that*, there is nothing that would separate globals from other globals (which are now used as a stack), and the collision (as well as lack of guard region) is entirely likely.

The overflow is also possible without threads, if you use coroutine style of programming (essentially user-level threads) via e.g. `makecontext`/`swapcontext` or a similar mechanism.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, except this is a single-threaded application.